# Post login redirect logic does not work with TestCafe roles

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm writing e2e test for a React SPA. I have login logic that works as follow:

1. If the user access a protected route without being logged in, the route is saved in localStorage (`post_login_redirect`) then the user is redirected to login page.
2. After a successful login, if `post_login_redirect` exists in localStorage, the user is redirected to the saved route, otherwise he is redirected to home (`/`).

In my test I call useRole in the fixture beforeEach hook. See below:

```js
const adminUser = Role(
  `http://myapp.com/login`,
  async t => {
    await t
      .typeText('input[name="username"]', "admin@admin.com")
      .typeText('input[name="password"]', "12345")
      .click('button[type="submit"]');
  }
);

fixture("Some fixture").page("http://myapp.com/companies/").beforeEach(async t => {
  await t.useRole(adminUser);
});

test("Company list", async t => {
  await t.expect(Selector("div").withText("COMPANY LIST").exists).ok();
});
```

What happens when I run this test:

1. Testcafe navigates to `/companies`
2. My app code detects the user is not logged in, create `post_login_redirect` and redirect to `/login`
3. Testcafe execute my Role by navigating to `/login` and submitting the form
4. My app code redirects the user to `/` (instead of the intended `/companies/` saved in localStorage)
5. Testcafe navigates to `/login`

For what I could see, at step 3, the localStorage is being cleared which explains step 4.

Step 5 is not performed if I use `preserveUrl:true` on my Role. Anyhow it should navigate to `/companies` as it's the URL defined by my fixture.

I would expect either my localStorage from step 2 to be restored after the Role execution or either Testcafe to remember the actual URL it needs to navigate to after the Role execution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your test seems to be correct, and TestCafe should work with it. The use of the Roles mechanism should not clear localStorage, so this is unexpected that your `post_login_redirect` value is cleared.

We would like to assist you in researching the issue. Please create a separate issue on GitHub using the following link and share your project or create a minimal example that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md.

If you cannot share your project on GitHub, you can send it at support@devexpress.com

Comment: Please note that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to further research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us (mailto:support@devexpress.com) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: Thansk Alex. I'll do that and try to recreate a minimal reproduction app

Comment: Issue report: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6269